# Preserving HTML content when parsing XML using nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, xml, cdata

I'm trying to parse third party delivered XML files that contain html in one of the nodes, and avoiding parsing the html (which is not wrapped in CDATA unfortunately). For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<News>
<Keywords>[..]</Keywords>
<Title>[..]</title>
<Body>
<Body.Content>[BODY_CONTENT_IN_HTML]</Body.Content>
</Body>
</News
</xml>
```

Trying to preserve the body content as an html string. I tried xml2js, but it parses the html, and if I try to reverse it for that node I don't get the same html back. Does anyone know how I could achieve this (parse the rest of the xml object, but retrieve the contents of the body.content node as text)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try just treating the xml as a string and splitting it until you extract the html.

For example:

```
let str = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<News>
<Keywords>[..]</Keywords>
<Title>[..]</title>
<Body>
<Body.Content><html><body>Hello, world!</body></html></Body.Content>
</Body>
</News
</xml>
`;
let target = str.split('Content>')[1].split('</Body')[0];
console.log(target);
```

Output:

```
<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>
```